# Verify Toast using Monkey Talk

Tags: android, mobile, automation, automated-tests, monkeytalk

Is there any way to verify the toast appearing in android applications using Monkey talk? I am not able to verify the toast as no specific id is not given for the toast. While searching i have seen that it is possible to verify a toast by extending monkey talk. Is it possible to verify?

Comment: Better you should try it *yourself*

Comment: i have tried but since i was not able to get an answer, i posted it here to get a help.